# Trying to import Local Folders from data recovery into Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

The data recovery software that I used, r-linux, created folder  $Inodeindx00a-00001 there's a 98mb inbox file and an inbox.msf file in the folder but when I click on the inbox in Thunderbird no mail shows What to do? I think .msf files can be deleted?

Answer (score 0):

The `.msf` file is an index file and can be deleted.

An mbox file can be opened in Thunderbird by moving it into `~/.thunderbird/########.default-default/Mail/Local Folders` (where `########` is a string unique to each account) while Thunderbird is closed. When restarting Thunderbird, it will appear as a folder under "Local Folders". See the [mozilla support page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-thunderbird-stores-user-data#w_how-to-find-your-profile) for details on how you can find a profile folder.

Comment: Are mbox files the files without extensions? Also I said msf not msl There's no msl files

Comment: I corrected the extension of the index files indeed.